# Proper way to deploy a Cloud Function for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Trying to deploy the simplest Cloud Function for Firebase:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
})
```

I've ran `firebase init` and selected `functions`.

The Firebase CLI has created a folder named 'functions' with `index.js` and `package.json` inside it. the index file contains the above function.

Then I ran `firebase deploy --only functions` and got a message in my terminal that the function was deployed. According to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions), I should have gotten a link to the function.

Instead, I got a link to my project's console. There is no sign of the function being deployed on the firebase web console functions section.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you uncomment the sample function that you found in index.js?  If you actually deployed the function, the https link to it would appear just below the link to to the console.

Comment: thought i did.. but i didn't. it works now. thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's surprising! Some things you could try:

- Double-check that your code matches the examples. Are there any mistakes  that snuck in while copy-pasting? Your symptoms could indicate that Cloud Functions doesn't see your "helloWorld" as an exported function, for example.
- Run the command again, to see if the problem persists. During beta it's not unthinkable that there may be some temporary errors that make your deployment fail, possibly in this surprising way.
- Update your Firebase CLI to the latest version: `npm install -g firebase-tools`.
- If none of those help, try [contacting the free troubleshooting support](https://firebase.google.com/support/). They can dig into your specific project and find out what's up.